# Microsoft.Extensions.X Version 7.0.0 Issue - .NET 7 FunctionApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-functions

I've just started upgrading my functionapps to .NET 7. I've updated them all to use the .NET 7 SDK and all of the `Microsoft.Extensions.X` deps in my project to 7.0.0.

I'm getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. .

Having had similar issues when upgrading to .NET 6, I had to upgrade my functions to the V4 runtime.

However, they're already on the V4 runtime and [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#languages) suggests that V4 supports .NET 7.

[image: Table from MS]

Is this a case of Microsoft just not having updated all of its function runners or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please provide details such as how you're upgrading (`.csproj` code) and the dependencies you have in .NET 6 with brief code/functionality

Comment: There are lot of change differences between .NET 6 Isolated to .NET 7 Isolated in Azure Functions. Have you gone through this Migration of .NET 6 to .NET Isolated worker of Azure Functions [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net7%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp)?

Comment: @HariKrishna - No, I don't think we're running on Isolated workers. The upgrade has been changing the target framework in the csproj from net6.0 -> net7.0

Comment: Current month Update - .NET 7 in Azure Functions is supported by leveraging the .NET Isolated Worker process. as mentioned in this Microsoft TechCommunity [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/announcing-the-net-7-for-azure-functions-isolated-worker-process/ba-p/3671398)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Table of which you have shown providing the general details like Compatible Runtime Languages & Versions with Azure Functions but not the In-Process or Out-of-Process Type.

Current month Update - .NET 7 in Azure Functions is supported by leveraging the .NET Isolated Worker process. as mentioned in this Microsoft TechCommunity [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/announcing-the-net-7-for-azure-functions-isolated-worker-process/ba-p/3671398)

If you click on the `.NET 7.0` shown in the same table, you will see another table like `.NET 7.0` came in Isolated Worker Process.

[image]