# Azure function v4 migration. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, nuget-package

I'm currently migrating an Azure Function from v2 to **Azure Functions** **v4**. I already migrated my project to **.NET6** and fixed all the package reference errors. I have in the solution 3 projects which I adjusted to **.NET6 and Azure Function v4**. For that I edited the .csproj files of each of those projects and upgraded/substituted packages which are not working with .NET6. The project file of each project looks like:

**Azure Function Project:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.11.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.7.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.18.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.33" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="5.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.8.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.48.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCM.1.z\x.1.z.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="2.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="1.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="3.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Second Project:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.11.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.7.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Devices" Version="1.38.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.33" />
      <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.28.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.6.80" />
      <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="6.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="UnitsNet" Version="4.149.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\x.1.w\x.1.w.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Third Project:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I **build** the project I got **no errors**. But when I **debug** the project I got an **exception** which looks like:

**Exception**:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll.
> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll but was not handled in user code
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

I have tried the last two weeks **different packages** since when I googled this error, the suggestion was to see which packages are not supported by **package**:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />`. I analyzed all my packages. After changing them back and force I got still the same error.

**Can anyone help me and say what exactly I have to change?**

Comment: "Version=7.0.0.0". I had lots of problems when upgrading when this version was proposed by VisualStudio. I would get those errors as 7.0.0.0 relies on .net7 whereas my functions are .net6 in Azure. I had to delete the bin/ and obj/ directories to get rid of the errors and clean/rebuild all. Not deleting those directories and the errors persisted even after moving down a version.
This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368240/microsoft-extensions-x-version-7-0-0-issue-net-7-functionapp

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

As @Codebrane said, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0` has the issues in working with Azure Functions v4 Version and it has been shown practically in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74473381).

- Try by downgrading the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` to `Version 6.0.0` and check.
- `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` depends on the NuGet Packages related to the Code but these can be suggested by VS IntelliSense and installed automatically, or it shows these packages required.
- Also, NuGet Packages varies between In-Process and Out-of-Process worker type in Azure Functions. Refer to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74368240/16630138) of my threads for more information.

Comment: Hi @Hari. What exactly do you mean by downgrade Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions to Version 6.0.0? Since I don't have that package in my .csproj file declared. When I declare it then it cant even build with the error: 
Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade: **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 7.0.0 to 6.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.**

Comment: As you have mentioned could not load file or assembly the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` package

Comment: I was unable to downgrade it to 6.0.0. , due to dependency issue

@Sammy, if you have fixed it, please update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I am building an Azure function as `v4` in `net6`. Since I also got the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` regarding library `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstraction 7.0.0` when starting up the function,
I downgraded to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 6.0.0` and also had to downgrade other dependencies such as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to `6.0.12` and, since I am using PostgreSQL also `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` to  `6.0.8`. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by including the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 6.0.0` and building it. To include this package doesn't solve the problem directly it just shows which packages have a conflict. By downgrading these conflicting packages the project could be debugged. To check which packages are conflicting you have to  open up the packages on the right side in visual studio and look where is a exclamation mark. Then you have to analyze these packages to know on what version you have to downgrade them. It changes from project to project.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps others, my case was using .NET 6 in-process. Compile was successful, but debug failed with the same message as posted but for version 6.0.0.0. moved past that error by noticing in the debug window the Function Runtime Version was 3.x.  I followed the suggestion on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=net6-in-proc%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows to update the value of project property AzureFunctionsVersion from v3 to v4.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>My.Namespace</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR:

[**Upgrading my functions to v4/.net7/dotnet-isolated**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-1-version-4?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=v4%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows) finally fixed it for me.  Reviewing a fresh Azure Function (dotnet-isolated) project was also very helpful (Program.cs changes, ILogger to ILoggerFactory changes, etc)

### Full Version:

During my fight with this issue I could certainly see that the dll in question is excluded from the bin folder but is in the lib folder.  Copying the dll manually did get me passed that one error I believe, but I think I just ran into another one.  Plus a manual copy step would have been pretty dirty.

Here's what didn't work for me:

- Including the package in the top level function application
- Downgrading the package (I didn't go below 6 though)
- [Including _FunctionsSkipCleanOutput](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1518) in the csproj file
- Downgrading the project to .net 6

Part of this might have been me not realizing that .net 7 supports ONLY the isolated model but I still never got it to work under .net 6.  But there were a lot of advantages anyway going to the isolated model, including the DownstreamApi middleware working right out of the box without a custom ITokenA

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue when trying out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-connector/how-to-integrate-mysql?tabs=dotnet#sample-codes) example. Downgrading a few Azure dependencies here and there eventually solved the issue.