# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions not found in Azure Function - .NET 7

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I have a simple Azure Function which was running in .NET Core 3.1

I am now trying to update it to .NET 7 version 4.x and Im getting a very unhelpful message

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Has anyone come across this?

My packages are shown below

[image]

Even more annoying is that when I try to create a new function even though I have the latest Visual Studio I dont see .NET 7, only .NET 6 which is of no help either

The documentation on MS has instructions that havent been updated since 17.4 was in preview

Can anyone help please?

Paul

Comment: which VS version you have?

Comment: please check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1729)

Comment: Visual Studio 17.4.3

Comment: @viveknuna that link has sooo much on it, does this mean I cant use EF Core 7 with Azure Functions and .NET 7? Surely not??

Answer (score 0):

> I am now trying to update it to .NET 7 version 4.x and Im getting a very unhelpful message

(OR)

> though I have the latest Visual Studio I don’t see .NET 7

As of now, Only Isolated worker process is released in .NET 7 Azure Functions 4.x as shown in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2,cmd#supported-versions).

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60’. The system cannot find the file specified.

I found two issues [74368240](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74368240/16630138) and [74470489](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74470489/16630138) that says version 7.0.0 of **`Microsoft.X`** NuGet Package is having the issues and not compatible with .NET 7 Version which is not yet released.

Even the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions` you’re using is compatible with the .NET 7:

[image]

It does not work until the .NET 7 (In-process) is released for the Azure Functions 4.x version.