# Upgrade my Azure Function from .net Core 3.1 to .net Core 7.0. Error "'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstraction

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an Azure Function which run on .net core 3.1, but when i change the .net version from 3.1 to 7 i got this error:-

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

here is a screen shot:-

[image]

here is my csproj file:-

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="PnP.Core.Auth" Version="1.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any advice on this please?

I have installed `Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions -Version 7.0.0` but this did not fix the issue either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.Extensions.X Version 7.0.0 Issue - .NET 7 FunctionApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368240/microsoft-extensions-x-version-7-0-0-issue-net-7-functionapp)

Comment: @HariKrishna did not get what i need to do exactly ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. .NET 3.1 is in-process and .NET 7 is Isolated Worker Process type.
2. I can see your **.csproj** file code given in the question that you changed only .NET Framework and Azure Functions Version which is not complete configuration code for .NET 7 Isolated Process Azure Function and also you're missing few **Function Worker** package references in the **`.csproj`** file code.
3. Basic/Default .NET 7 Isolated Azure Functions Project contains the below code in **`.csproj`** file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

4. .NET 7 In-Process is not yet released and to convert from .NET 3.1 (In-Process Model) to .NET 7 (Isolated Worker Process), you need to write the .NET 7 Isolated Compatible NuGet Packages, code changes in the Function Code, `program.cs` file, etc.,

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net7,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for Migration Steps & Checks of Azure Functions V3 to V4 and One of the my answers SO #[74428448](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74428448/16630138) states the update of the supported available version in Azure Functions C#.